# How to get MySQL status variables every second?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL workbench 6.3 CE. I want to take the snapshots of MySQL status variables.

I want to store the values of status variables after every 1 second during the execution of query.

I can simply show the variables using 'show global status'. But I want to execute it automatically after every 1 second.

Comment: Store where? There's a lot of ambiguity in this question. If this is truly urgent and  you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: I created an event: 
 Create Event status_variables_every_second

On schedule

Every 1 second  

DO show global status ; 

but I don't know how to execute event. I want to execute it at the start of query execution till the end of the query execution

Comment: Create a long-running script that runs the code every second? You can do `sleep(1)` between each call.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sorry halfer if my 'urgent' word bothers you. I'll be careful next time.

Comment: here is the MySQL query : use tpch;
select
 l_returnflag,l_linestatus,sum(l_quantity) as sum_qty,sum(l_extendedprice) as sum_base_price,sum(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount)) as sum_disc_price,sum(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount) * (1 + l_tax)) as sum_charge,avg(l_quantity) as avg_qty,avg(l_extendedprice) as avg_price,
avg(l_discount) as avg_disc,
count(*) as count_order
from
 lineitem
where
 l_shipdate <= date '1998-12-01' 
group by
 l_returnflag,
 l_linestatus
order by
 l_returnflag,
 l_linestatus;
I want to run the show_status procedure during the execution of this query.

Comment: yes I also created procedure using sleep: here is the code: CREATE PROCEDURE show_status () BEGIN while 1=1 do do sleep(1); show global status; End while; END but I don't know how to run this procedure and query at the same time. Is there any way to run this procedure during the execution of the query?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a procedure and a query at the same time by having two separate connections.  Workbench is a handy tool, but you should learn to use the mysql commandline tool, too.

The query is rather simple.  `INDEX(l_shipdate)` is likely to be the best for it.

The real way to speed up the query (assuming that is your ultimate goal) is to build and maintain a "Summary table" of daily or monthly subtotals.  Then sum the sums and sum the counts.  Avg is `(SUM(sums)/SUM(counts))`.

More discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Be cautious about running (via `EVENT` or `cron`) any code that might take longer than the interval time.  If it gets behind, it is likely to cascade and bring the server down, or at least slow things down severely.  For that reason, I much prefer the `WHILE` loop.

Comment: Thank you Rick! How can I have two separate connections at the same time? And how can I be able to run the procedure (show status) only during the execution of the query? And the above query is from TPC-h benchmark. I am not required to change the query. I just want to take snapshots (every 5 seconds) of status variables while running the queries.

Comment: If you are on Windows: Start > Run > cmd > mysql.  Do that again to get another window.  run as many as you need.

Comment: thanks Rick! thats helpful.. I can do the same in MySQL workbench by pressing (ctrl+shift+T). It will open another tab.